# Use drush make to load only modules?

Tags: 7, drush

I have a dev site with many modules.  I have another dev site on a different server that I'd like to populate with the same modules.  I can zip 'em up and move the file, or use rsync, but I wanted to see if drush-make would do it faster.

I can create only modules without core using: "drush make --no-core makefile.make" within the module directory but this creates the sites/all/modules directory hierarchy.

How can you use drush make to just build the modules in the modules directory without that structure?

Answer (score 8):

If you run `drush make --contrib-destination=sites/mysite`, then modules will be placed in sites/mysite/modules.  rsync is going to be faster than Drush make. (**Edit:** This speed comparison presumes roughly equal transfer speeds between the endpoints. I can see how make might be faster if you have a fast connection from the target to d.o, but a slow connection between the source and the target.)

If you want to create a makefile for an existing site, you may use `drush generate-makefile`, or build a whole installation profile with [drush generate-profile](http://drupal.org/node/1368242).

Comment: That didn't work. As a test I made a directory, test_drush, in the site root and put the makefile in it.  The command: 'drush make --no-core --contrib-destination=all/modules makefile.make' still creates that hierarchy in that directory.  If the hierarchy test_drush/all/modules already exists, it ends up like this, no matter how I try it: test_drush/all/modules/modules/module_xyz, even if I have this to start: test_drush/all, and no modules sub-directory.  I think rsync would be really slow from my pc as my upload speed is poor.  Rsync is fast as a file sync if the files already exist.

Comment: I am unclear as to why you are trying to put your modules at test_drush/all/modules.  If you specify sites/mysite, then the target will be sites/all/modules, so it is expected that --contrib-destination=all/modules would give you all/modules/modules.  Did you try --contrib-destination=all?

Comment: I was just testing the results of drush make because I didn't want to screw up the file structure if it failed. I punted and used rsync.  Maybe what you suggested would work - I'll try it again later.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea to run drush make on an empty site, especially when testing; then you can just blow away the whole thing after the test. It would also make a better test if you make the modules install at their final intended destination (e.g. sites/all/modules).